# Not able to fetch details at random order from API by using JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, access-control

There's this `randomQuote` API that I want to call using `jQuery`. When I call the API using the specified params in postman, I am getting random quotes on every click. But when I used `jQuery` in my webpage, I am getting a default quote and its not changing. 
the objective is to fetch a random quote and display it on the web page whenever a user clicks on a `button`. I am using `JSONP` to bypass the `Access-Control`.

This is my query

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click").each(function(index){
   $(this).on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(key) {
  $("#quote span").replaceWith(key[0].content + "<p>— " + key[0].title + "</p>");
         });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please refer this link to know about the API
https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/

Comment: i hope i fully cover you with the two snippets. You could use `html()` or `replaceWith()` on the correct element with the correct way and have the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution.As it was said in the previous comments, a loop is not neccesary.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content="";
  $("#click").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("//quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?", function(key) {
     content=key[0].content + "<p>— " + key[0].title + "</p>";
      $("#quote-form").html(content);
      console.log(content);
    });
    
    $("#quote-form").css({"font-family":"lucida console", "font-size": "20px","color":"rgb(255,255,150)"});
     
  });
 
});
```

The `html` method should be used instead of `replaceWith`. (Refer to the explanation of the previous answer of why `replaceWith` shouldn't be used here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `replaceWith` incorrectly. You are replacing the quote and span so that it no longer has an id. That's why it updates the first time but not the second time. Please see doc

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

```
$("#quote").replaceWith("<div id=quote><span>" + key[0].content + "<p>— " + key[0].title + "</span></p></div");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgi/e57zjgLb/. Make sure fiddle is http so API works.

Comment: Hi @andrewgi. Thank you for the response. I added an `each` loop to execute the `on click` function whenever the user clicks the button. But its not working. Can you help me out on this?

Comment: Sure I can help. Did your replace your quote line with the one shown above? A loop is not necessary. You can also check out the fiddle for a working example.

Comment: Thank you @andrewgi. Yes I had replaced my code with the update one. Can you briefly tell what fiddle is, how and why should we implement it? Because I didn't find much information about it on the internet. Appreciate your help

Comment: And to add to this, in Postman, I could get random quotes whenever I fired the API. This might have been happening because it doesn't requires `JSONP`as a parameter because there is no such thing as `single origin policy` in postman, unlike the browsers, which have a strict `same origin policy`.

Comment: are you using http or https? on the fiddle with http you can get random quotes as well

Comment: Hi @andrewgi. I am using http. I am getting the output when I click the button. But the quotes are not changing when I try clicking again. Is it because the function executes only once and is a loop necessary?

Comment: a loop is not necessary. it's because you are erasing the id of the quote in your `replaceWith` so jQuery doesn't know what to replace the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine like this.

```js
function getGetOrdinal(n) {
   var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
       v=n%100;
   return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}
var i = 1;
setInterval(function(){
console.clear();
 $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?",{beforeSend: function( ) {
    console.log("started "+getGetOrdinal(i)+" Ajax request");
  }}, function(a) {
  $("#quote span").html(i+": "+a[0].content + "<p>&mdash; " + a[0].title + "</p>")
}).done(function(){
  console.log("finished "+getGetOrdinal(i)+" Ajax request");  
  i++;
});

 }, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quote"><span></span></div>
```

or like this

```js
function getGetOrdinal(n) {
   var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
       v=n%100;
   return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}
var i = 1;
setInterval(function(){
console.clear();
 $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=?",{beforeSend: function( ) {
    console.log("started "+getGetOrdinal(i)+" Ajax request");
  }}, function(a) {
  $("#quote span").replaceWith("<span>"+i+": "+a[0].content + "<p>&mdash; " + a[0].title + "</p></span>")
}).done(function(){
  console.log("finished "+getGetOrdinal(i)+" Ajax request");  
  i++;
});

 }, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quote"><span></span></div>
```

**The reason your code fails is because in the first run of `replaceWith()` you remove the element `span` therefor there is no matching `$("#quote span")` object in the document any more in order to `replaceWith()` the second post.**